# Hibernate criteriaQuery createAlias equivalent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, createcriteria

I am looking at upgrading my hibernate to use JPA criteriaQuery :-( and need to find a way to implement an alias in JPA eg:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
....
@ManyToOne(..)
public MyDetail getMyDetail() { 
return myDetail;  
}
}

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
....
criteria.createAlias("myDetail", "md");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("md.active", true));
```

I have been through the hibernate docs but they seem to have only covered trivial examples and glossed over hibernate specific functionality.

Cheers Greg

Comment: Any basic JPA documentation would tell you such. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql_criteria.html

Comment: The join is in the @ManyToOne on MyDetail class, maybe I need to create another join just for the query?

Comment: if you need to refer to something other than candidate then yes you need to join ...

Comment: @ManyToOne style implicit joins won't be supported.  I have loads and loads of queries using createAlias  :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can create alias in JPA CriteriaQuery on entityRoot

```
Root<A> entityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(A);
entityRoot.join("b", JoinType.LEFT).alias("b");
```

Comment: This doesn't help a whole lot. The `alias` returns a weird `Selection<A>` which it's unclear how to use. You should have provided a more concrete example with how `Selections`s are actually used.